# Store Hadoop output to local mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop

I've seen questions relating to storing the hadoop HDFS output to MongoDB, but I have not seen how I can store my local hadoop output to my local db. 
I know I need to use the mongodb connector from here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop

I've added the dependency to my POM.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's my class to run the job:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException, InvalidDataException {

        Job job = new Job();

        job.setJarByClass(hadoop.TwitterJob.class);
        job.setJobName("Inverted Index for Twitter Data");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("src/output/")); // change this to output to mongodb

        job.setMapperClass(InvertedIndexMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(hadoop.InvertedIndexReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can directly output to mongodb locally? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/README.md:

> Write data out in .bson format, which can then be imported to any
>   MongoDB database with mongorestore

From https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Using-.bson-Files:

> To write the output of a job to .bson files, set
>   mongo.job.output.format to com.mongodb.hadoop.BSONFileOutputFormat or
>   use
>   MongoConfigUtil.setOutputFormat(com.mongodb.hadoop.BSONFileOutputFormat.class)

And this seems straight forward example you can test it out

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/examples/sensors/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/examples/sensors/Devices.java